# Loading assets in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my 2D game, I have nearly 1000 sprite assets grouped into a few dozen of multi-sprite images, with the global size of 4 Mb or so. I don't know yet much about loading in Unity, so I want to ask you about the best strategy to access such a big number of sprites. I don't think it would be a good idea to reference them all in the inspector through a public array, or is it?

As far as I am starting to understand, there are at least two ways to access the assets dynamically: (1) placing them into the Resources folder and loading them as resources, or (2) loading them by a slash syntax. But what are the pros and cons?

To make the problem easier (or harder), it's not ascertained what part of the assets would be used in which game mission/level, so I actually intend to load them all at once. If I understand correctly, this wouldn't need any special loading operation, just finding the assets right away. Or is it a problem for the memory or loading time?

Comment: *"loading them by a slash syntax."* Not sure what this is. Can you explain this more?

Comment: [Here is a con to use the Resources folder](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder) `2.1. Best Practices for the Resources System - 
Don't use it.`

Comment: @Programmer: I guess, this is what happens when you use AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath method. Can't _explain_ it though - like I said, I am just trying to understand how different approaches work.

Comment: @Hellium: Thanks for the warning :) I would prefer to know what to _use_ rather than _not use_, but the global guide seems to give more answers.